# How do signed transactions in a single Ethereum node's transaction pool propagate to mining nodes?

Tags: transactions, mining, pending-transactions, txpool

How does a transaction get from a regular node to the rest of the network?

What are the incentives for regular nodes to broadcast signed transactions?